# Grails Fixtures alternative

Tags: grails, grails-orm, fixtures

Could someone advice a good alternative to the [grails fixtures plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/fixtures?skipRedirect=true) 
It seems that the plugin project is not active any more, doc page shows 404 no recent commits and etc. Moreover, the plugin works buggy with new versions of grails (3.3.5).

We are using fixtures to initialize data for dev and test environments. And we like the concise way of defining entities and their many-to-many associations in bootstrap, which provides fixtures plugin.

So, any suggestions are welcome.

Thx.

Comment: Just a comment because I don't think this is really the "answer" you're looking for: per https://github.com/gpc/fixtures/pull/8 it looks like someone already upgraded the plugin to 3.3.x, so you could try that.  If that doesn't work, the master is at 3.2.7, and it shouldn't be hard for you to fork a branch and upgrade to 3.3.whatever if needed.  I'm guessing that would be a lot simpler than finding a replacement if you're using this in a lot of places already.

Comment: @Daniel we have used this build of fixture. It fails on some one to many relations with session not found exception.

Comment: OK, I didn't actually try it but was optimistic!  Hopefully someone else will have an actual answer for you!  Good luck.